# Erlang: error_logger and overload protection

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

Say I have an Erlang system which sometimes go nasty and produces a lot of warnings, which will be logged to file, the system should still functional properly if the logging doesn't block disk IO, (i.e. the logs are "more or less expected"). (This is a real world scenario, not something I makeup)

The `error_logger` comes with erlang doesn't have overload protection, so if the amount of logs are really big, the logging will block disk IO and possibly cause system to malfunction.

My question is, why `error_logger` doesn't have overload protection by default, is it because that this feature is not actually needed if you design your architecture right? or is it because that this is some kind of advanced feature, if you need this feature, you should use another library, like `lager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that overload protection is a feature, and that is a matter of **implementation** (and/or **configuration**).

Overload protection is perhaps a nice feature to have in a logging toolkit, useful for some people, even if probably most people won't need it, but error_logger is really a logging **interface**, one designed to support arbitrary implementations (each with disparate configuration depending on their features) that the developer/integrator/user can choose to plug in, depending on their requirements.

This may not be exhaustive, but things that immediately come to mind which change logging requirements are:

- application (some applications obviously log more/less/differently than others)
- host environment (capabilities are different for traditional or SSD storage for example)
- use case of the application (an end user or developer might deploy with configurations that mean more or less logging)
- local infrastructure and standards (some organisations might use only local logs, but others may use syslog everywhere, religiously)
- external or 3rd party environmental factors (such as another network service which talks to the application/node, causing logging)

It's really important to decouple the logging **interface** from **implementation**, because:

- a developer might change their mind about the logging implementation part way through a project, and the decoupling means this is easy
- a system administrator might need to modify or override the developers default, because of host, use case, local infrastructure and other environmental factors, etc, some of which the developer may not be able to anticipate

**Thus, because it's an interface, error_logger doesn't and shouldn't have overload protection; it's outside error_logger's remit.**

I freely admit that it may be possible to make plausible arguments for including some implementation in an interface, and I can imagine arguments for including features like overload protection in error_logger despite what I've said, but it's a slippery slope. I would choose purity and simplicity instead; I think it's worth keeping error_logger lean and mean rather than allowing additional bulk to creep into it that will affect the performance of every logging implementation everywhere. Take that path and before you know it the limitations won't be the disk I/O blocking, it'll be error_logger itself because it's become bloated, and there won't be anything to be done about it other than invent a new error logger to use instead.